# Curl command (or headless python alternative) for scraping Bank Holding Company (FR Y-9C) data from new www.ffiec.gov site?

Tags: python, curl, screen-scraping

In the past, bank Holding Company data on form FR Y-9C was easily downloadable from the Chicago website. A simple curl line would do the trick.

This has now changed, the repository originally going back to 1986 has now moved to [this](https://www.ffiec.gov/npw/FinancialReport/FinancialDataDownload?selectedyear=2021) site. It requires clicking before one can download.

I want to download daily updates of the zip files (e.g. `BHCF20210630.ZIP`) using a headless Linux machine and avoid using selenium.

I tried to obtain the zip-file using the link below, and variations of that link, but alas, no result:

[https://www.ffiec.gov/nwp/FinancialReport/ReturnBHCFZipFiles?zipfilename='BHCF20210630.ZIP'](https://www.ffiec.gov/nwp/FinancialReport/ReturnBHCFZipFiles?zipfilename=%27BHCF20210630.ZIP)

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with link you posted in the end (remove single quotes from file name)

Comment: Use `Copy as curl` from browser network tab after a manual download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, `Copy as curl` does the job. For Firefox, I installed the [cliget](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cliget/) extension and followed this instruction for [copy as curl](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/copyas). Download the file and cliget will alert you about the curl command.